# Get based on only month and year from table using mysql store producer but apply date parameter?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

```
Declare      
   @date1 date = '2015-12-01'
   ,@date2 date = '2015-12-30'

BEGIN

Declare @date_u char = Month(@date1)
        ,@date_v char = Month(@date2)

Select 
       STD.StoreNo As StoreNo
       ,CheckDate as Date
       ,ProductBarCode as ProductBarCode
       ,SUM( StocktakingQty)AS ProducQty
       From StockTakingDetail STD
Inner Join
(Select StoreNo,CheckNo,CheckDate 
              From StockTakingMain SM )StocktakingMain 
   On STD.CheckNo =StockTakingMain.CheckNo
   where year(CheckDate) between @date_u and @date_v 
    group By STD.StoreNo,STD.ProductBarCode,CheckDate
             End
```

Actually, I want to show daily inventory, but once a month only.

They use to take inventory in the warehouse. I cannot able to fill dates gap without the data. So, I planned to use month and year only to get data . But, I can't be able to find a way how to take input parameter only month and year from date.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Table structure, sample data and expected results would be helpful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want your `where` clause to look like this?

```
where year(CheckDate) * 100 + month(CheckDate) between year(@date1) * 100 + month(@date1) and
                                                       year(@date2) * 100 + month(@date2)
```

If so, I would really go fo:

```
where CheckDate >= date_sub(@date1, interval 1 - day(@date1)) and
      CheckDate < date_add(date_sub(@date2, interval 1 - day(@date2)), interval 1 month)
```

Comment: thanks a lot !! your first code was working but second one shows some error !!

Comment: Are you sure you are using MySQL?

Comment: yes !! Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near '1'.